# Pass NSIndexPath between UITableViews

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a `UITableView` showing data from a plist file. For this table view, I've simply made an `NSArray` from the contents of the plist file and fed the data into each cell. But when a cell is tapped, I need the next table view controller to know the index path of the cell that was tapped so that this view controller knows which item in the array to show details for.  I've tried the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    staffDetailView = [[StaffDetailViewController alloc] init];
    [staffDetailView setSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushStaffDetailView" sender:self];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Above, I'm attempting to pass the index path of the tapped cell to an `NSIndexPath` object that I've created in the new view controller.

The next table view controller's header file:

```
@interface StaffDetailViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
    NSArray *staffArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *staffArray;
```

Here I define the `selectedIndexPath` object that was set in the previous view controller.

But when I try to access the `selectedIndexPath` object to display the relevant data, the object appears to be `nil`:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *header;
    if (section == 0) {
        NSString *name = [[staffArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Staff Member"];
        NSArray *splitStaffArray = [name componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
        NSString *lastName = [splitStaffArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *firstName = [splitStaffArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *consolidatedName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
        NSString *assignment = [[staffArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Assignment"];
        header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", consolidatedName, assignment];
        return header;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Am I accessing the `selectedIndexPath` object incorrectly? Is there a superior method for passing the correct index path to the next view controller?

Comment: Why not simply forwarding the object instance instead of the indexPath of it?

Comment: I have multiple instances of objects to display, I thought that for efficiency's sake, it would be better to only pass the index path and let the next view controller take care of retrieving the data. I'll try that approach once more, though.

Comment: Taking that approach returns null.

Comment: You will have done it wrong then - show us your alternative code within the question as an additional attempt for solving your problem.

Comment: do as 'Till' recommends. pass the object at index path to the child view controller. its an unnecessary overhead to re-fetch from another instance of the array. just pass what you need.

Comment: Does it make a large difference memory-wise?

Comment: will depend on what your object is. try it out in instruments but I would have thought it was much more efficient to pass the object. otherwise you are loading your entire array of objects into memory.

Comment: When I pass the individual object though (an NSString for example) using a setter like I did with the index path, it displays null when NSLogged in the next view controller. Really weird. Any ideas? I'm using the code you see above.

Comment: I agree with @till as well. You would have to load the entire array and then iterate through, which would load your entire object graph instead of just passing a reference to a single instance.

Comment: Thanks @JackLawrence. When I try passing individual objects though (like the `passedName` which you see above, the object is null when NSLogged in its view controller. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revised the first table view controller's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushStaffDetailView" sender:self];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [staffDetailView setSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];
    [staffDetailView setPassedName:[[staffArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Staff Member"]];   

}
```

It seemed that for some reason I needed to perform the segue before accessing that view controller's instance variables.  Strange that I couldn't just `alloc init` the view controller its self. Anyhow, the index path is now being correctly pushed across view controllers.

Answer (score -3):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //I ll use NSUserDefaults to store tha indexpath. Indexpath.row is an int property, so convert to NSNumber 

    NSNumber *ip = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexpath.row];
    NSUserDefaults *saveIP=[NSUserDefaults standartuserdefaults];
    [saveIP setObject: ip foKey:@"theIndexPath"];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushStaffDetailView" sender:self];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [staffDetailView setSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];
    [staffDetailView setPassedName:[[staffArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Staff Member"]];   

}
```

I other view controller retrieve saved object(data) with the code below

```
NSNumber *theIndexpath= [[NSUserDefaults standartuserdefaults] objectForKey:@"theIndexPath"];
```

Note: NSUserDefaults may not be a good idea but it was very easy, and still works for my app

Comment: This is terrible code. `NSUserDefaults` should only be used for settings, not arbitrary data. Furthermore, you're limiting yourself to one tableview for the entire app since you are using keys which correspond to integers that are not unique. More glaringly obvious, however, is that there are numerous spelling errors in your code which would make this fail to compile.